# Spring custom annotation - how to make it part of a library?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I've created a custom annotation (in Spring 3.05) that works great.  I'd like to take that code and make it part of a library, packaged in a jar file, so I don't have to include my custom annotation code in each web app I write.

I'm unable to get Spring to act on the annotation, however.  My library jar is in my web app's classpath and I tried scanning for it in `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.annotation.pkg" />
```

The field annotated with my custom annotation continues to be null.

Ideally I'd like to this to just work with a minimum of fuss and configuration, but so far I haven't had any success.

What part of Spring's wiring am I missing to get my custom annotation recognized when it's part of an external library?

**Update**

Here is how I "solved" it...just had to read a little more closely.  In each context file (i.e. applicationContext.xml, dispatch-servlet.xml) I added the line:

```
<bean class="my.annotation.CustomInjector" />
```

...where my `CustomInjector implements BeanPostProcessor`.  I based this on the code at this blog post: [Implementing Seam style @Logger injection with Spring](http://www.tzavellas.com/techblog/2007/03/31/implementing-seam-style-logger-injection-with-spring/).

The author says I needed to do exactly what I did, so bad on me for not reading thoroughly.  Why, though, is adding that bean definition required?  Maybe Spring annotations are configured similarly under the hood - I just don't get why having the jar file on the classpath isn't enough.

Comment: I doubt your probem has to do anything with the fact that the annotation is in a separate jar. Spring scans what it finds in the classpath, and does not care which jar some class is loaded from. Are you sure that the class containing the null field is scanned?

Comment: Yes, because I have `@Autowired` elements in the file.  I updated my question - if you have the time perhaps you can look at my follow-up question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your custom annotation annotated with the [@Component](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) annotation? From the [Spring reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters):

> By default, classes annotated with @Component, @Repository, @Service, @Controller, or a custom annotation that itself is annotated with @Component are the only detected candidate components.

Alternatively, you could add a custom [include-filter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters) to the `component-scan` element in your XML configuration.

Comment: It wasn't, but when I added `@Component` it broke the annotation for the library itself.  I added information to my question because I did find something that worked; I don't understand why it works however.

Comment: This is a different problem than I answered before. [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp) beans are not different from other Spring beans in a sense that they also need to be declared in order for Spring to operate on them.